# ffmpeg Invalid data found when processing input

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to download a specific part of a youtube video with this code:

```
step=`youtube-dl -g -f 'bestvideo[ext=mp4]' https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pMntMsHTDZ0`
ffmpeg -nostdin  -i "$step" -ss 00:00:10.00 -t 00:00:02.00 -c copy frames/out.mp4
```

but I'm getting this error:

```
https://manifest.googlevideo.com/api/manifest/dash/requiressl/yes/source/youtube/id/a4c9ed32c1d30d9d/itag/0/ei/fG7iXMihC8_oxwK0qJ-YAQ/playback_host/r6---sn-n4g-jqbd.googlevideo.com/mm/31%2C26/mn/sn-n4g-jqbd%2Csn-5hne6n7s/ms/au%2Conr/mv/m/pl/22/hfr/all/as/fmp4_audio_clear%2Cwebm_audio_clear%2Cwebm2_audio_clear%2Cfmp4_sd_hd_clear%2Cwebm2_sd_hd_clear/initcwndbps/716250/mt/1558343198/fvip/4/ip/79.86.92.133/ipbits/0/expire/1558364892/sparams/ip%2Cipbits%2Cexpire%2Crequiressl%2Csource%2Cid%2Citag%2Cei%2Cplayback_host%2Cmm%2Cmn%2Cms%2Cmv%2Cpl%2Chfr%2Cas%2Cinitcwndbps/signature/D046699C35F9AFF84334BAB20E1D8D4CA5318794.6EF1739E2ED134D16EBBE9242BDDE31F59801AAB/key/yt8: Invalid data found when processing input
```

I don't understand this error, and this code has worked for tens of videos I've downloaded before.

How to fix this or get more information on the error?